# Register a full trust proxy in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am attempting to prove out that you can use a full trust proxy with SharePoint online. If you take a look at [SPProxyOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.usercode.spproxyoperation.aspx) on MSDN, you'll see the little note that says `Available In SharePoint Online` under the assembly name. Great, fantastic!

But now how am I supposed to register my proxy with the user code service? All examples that I can find (that refer to a local environment), deploy a Farm solution and run the following code:

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    SPUserCodeService userCodeService = SPUserCodeService.Local;
    if (userCodeService != null)
    {
        string assemblyName = this.GetType().Assembly.FullName;
        SPProxyOperationType SendEmailOperation = new SPProxyOperationType(assemblyName, typeof(SendEmailProxy).FullName);
        userCodeService.ProxyOperationTypes.Add(SendEmailOperation);
        userCodeService.Update();
    }
    else { throw new ApplicationException("User Code Service not running."); }
}
```

Well the issue is pretty straight forward. Having a look at [SPUserCodeService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spusercodeservice.aspx)'s documentation, it does **NOT** state `Available In SharePoint Online`. If that is the case, how am I supposed to register my proxy, which is clearly (er, according to MSDN) supported.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder why this question received a down vote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is simple. There is no way for you to register custom operations, but if Microsoft created and published these operations you could use them from within the sandbox.

Comment: That's the thing...If I can't register them, then how can I use them? It would appear to me that you require both halves to make a whole.

Comment: imagine MS (or other hosting partner) register their custom proxies for you to use...

Comment: Thanks Wictor..Do you have any informational links? I'm not entirely sure of the services they provide to do such a thing. Are you referring to Azure?

Comment: MSFT will not accept any requests of this kind as of now, I don't know about the future. You have to think outside the box, or go for SharePoint Online Dedicated.

Comment: @Tim - Your best bet to see what they offer (what things are possible in the sandbox) is to check out the SharePoint Online Development Center on MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/gg153540.aspx). If you can't do it in SharePoint, look to Windows Azure (IMHO) which can call back into SharePoint Online (Office365). Resources here (http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2011/09/02/now-available-sharepoint-amp-windows-azure-developer-training-kit-ndash.aspx) and in this post for Azure>SP (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjohnson/archive/tags/sharepoint+online/).

Comment: Thanks Andrew. It was deceiving because the MSDN article said 'Available in SharePoint Online', so I'm not yet sure what that means. However, your two links give me the info I would need to get working with Azure.

Answer (score 2):

Of course Wictor is correct. Here is the exact place in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg622616.aspx) where the thing is stated:

> Because the assembly with the full-trust proxy operation must be deployed by a farm administrator as a farm solution, this technique cannot be used when farm deployment is not an option, such as when your solution is to be deployed to Microsoft SharePoint Online. [...]

So I guess you have to go with SP Client Object Model and/or Silverlight.